# PDF margins compromised when printing

Tags: pdf, printing, paper

When I was printing a PDF file downloaded from a Quebec website with A4 paper, the margins were seriously reduced, which resulted in an uncomplete print. (I assume they use Letter size there). 
Can someone help please?

Thank you.

Comment: Which PDF viewer are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Did you set the page scaling to shrink/fit the PDF to the printable area?